# MYSQL Max date group by two columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I want to get the latest create date between sender and receiver in my table where sender or receiver = 002 and then group by sender and receiver. At the end notify whether member is sender or receiver from the view of 002.

This is just a sample data.

table

```
id    sender    |    receiver    |       create_date
1      001              002           2015-10-13 10:30:01  
2      003              002           2015-11-06 15:30:59
3      001              002           2015-11-02 05:30:01
4      001              002           2015-11-03 11:08:22
5      002              004           2015-10-20 12:15:36
6      002              004           2015-11-03 17:35:10
7      002              005           2015-09-01 06:02:20
8      002              001           2015-11-06 15:10:32
```

---

**The result should look like this**

```
id    |    member    |    type    |       create_date
2           003          sender       2015-11-06 15:30:59
6           004         receiver      2015-11-03 17:35:10
7           005         receiver      2015-09-01 06:02:20
8           001         receiver      2015-11-06 15:10:32
```

---

So far I have tried:

1)

```
SELECT
    id,
    IF(sender <> '002', sender, receiver) AS member, 
    IF(sender <> '002', 'sender', 'receiver') AS type, 
    MAX(create_date) AS max_date
FROM
    table
WHERE
    sender = '002' OR receiver = '002'
GROUP BY
    member
```

This is the result i got at the end.

```
id    |    member    |    type    |       create_date
1           001          sender       2015-11-06 15:10:32
2           003          sender       2015-11-06 15:30:59
5           004         receiver      2015-11-03 17:35:10
7           005         receiver      2015-09-01 06:02:20
```

I struggle to get the latest current row but no problem with create_date.

2) I have tried using inner join as well.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        id,
        MAX(create_date) as max_date
    FROM
        table
    WHERE
        sender = '002' OR receiver = '002'        
) b ON b.max_date = a.create_date
```

This works well for retrieving latest row record only. But what if I need to retrieve rows with latest create_date but group by sender and receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly use a sub query to get the list of members and types with the dates, then get the max from that:-

```
SELECT member, type, MAX(create_date)
FROM
(
    SELECT sender AS member, 'sender' AS type, create_date
    FROM table
    WHERE receiver = '002'
    UNION
    SELECT receiver AS member, 'receiver' AS type, create_date
    FROM table
    WHERE sender = '002'
) sub0
GROUP BY member, type
```

The id is a minor issue. If required then it needs to join back against the table based on the member / type / create date to get it, or do a fiddle with GROUP_CONCAT:-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY create_date DESC), ',', 1), 
        member, 
        type, 
        MAX(create_date)
FROM
(
    SELECT id, sender AS member, 'sender' AS type, create_date
    FROM table
    WHERE receiver = '002'
    UNION
    SELECT id, receiver AS member, 'receiver' AS type, create_date
    FROM table
    WHERE sender = '002'
) sub0
GROUP BY member, type
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one single select, with a case

```
select 
case when sender='002' then receiver else sender end as member, -- # knowing that either sender or receiver are 002, take the other.
case when sender='002' then 'receiver' else 'sender' end as type,
max(date)
from table
where sender = '002' or receiver = '002'
group by 1,2
```

Comment: This is the way to go if you don't need `id`.

Comment: @vhu true, I missed that. If you want the ID you will have to do a join back to this. If the ID is in the same order as the create date though, you can just take the max(id) as well

Answer (score 1):

Here is a horribly ineffective way to do it, but it'll achieve correct results:

```
SELECT id, t.member, COALESCE(IF(sender<>2,'sender',NULL),'receiver') type, t.create_date 
FROM a
JOIN (
 SELECT COALESCE(IF(sender<>2,sender,NULL),receiver) member, MAX(create_date) create_date 
 FROM a GROUP BY member
) t on ((a.sender=t.member or a.receiver=t.member) AND a.create_date=t.create_date)
WHERE a.sender='002' OR a.receiver='002';
```

Inner sub-select will find you latest create_date for each involved member and outer select will find that specific row.